# Issue with modifying attributes on a Wordpress website (PHP)

Tags: php

I have a script responsible for the layout on a Wordpress page using the Traveler theme. I modified the order so that additional attributes appear below the description rather than at the bottom.

The current layout looks approximately like this:

1. Description
2. Attribute
3. Second attribute
4. Section 3

I would like to achieve the following effect:

1. Description
2. Attribute
3. Section 3
4. Second attribute

**However, I am not proficient in PHP. The script responsible for this looks as follows:**

```
...
                    <?php echo stt_elementorv2()->loadView('services/tour/single/item/infor', array('tour_type' => $tour_type)); ?>
                    <div class="st-hr"></div>
                    <?php echo stt_elementorv2()->loadView('services/common/single/description') ?>
                    <div id="st-attributes">
                        <?php echo stt_elementorv2()->loadView('services/common/single/attributes',['post_type' => 'st_tours']) ?>
                    </div>
                    
                    <?php echo stt_elementorv2()->loadView('services/tour/single/item/highlights') ?>
                    <?php echo stt_elementorv2()->loadView('services/tour/single/item/include-exclude') ?>
                    <?php echo stt_elementorv2()->loadView('services/tour/single/item/itenirary',['post_id'=>$post_id]) ?>
                    <?php echo stt_elementorv2()->loadView('services/tour/single/item/faq',['post_id'=>$post_id]) ?>
                    <?php echo stt_elementorv2()->loadView('services/tour/single/item/location',['post_id'=>$post_id]) ?>
                    <?php echo stt_elementorv2()->loadView('services/tour/single/item/discount'); ?>


                    <?php echo stt_elementorv2()->loadView('services/tour/single/item/review',['post_id' => $post_id]); ?>
                    <div class="stoped-scroll-section"></div>
                </div>
...
```

Is it possible to achieve this effect?

Comment: What is second attribute? (and what do you mean by 'attribute' in this context?) Where does it appear in the generated HTML, in the `<div id="st-attributes">` along with the first attribute? i.e. at the moment your generator code generates them both together from a single call?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.